# COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder708394864/bashrc: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a Docker image of a system on which I can traing and evaluate neural networks.

here is the link to the github repo in which I have uploaded the Dockerfile

https://github.com/sadimanna/codalab_instructions

When I build the Dockerfile using

`sudo docker build . -f ~/Documents/codalab_instructions/Dockerfile`

Everything is going fine till `Step 25/26` where I am getting the error

```
Step 25/26 : COPY bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder708394864/bashrc: no such file or directory
```

Can't understand why this error is occuring.

This problem is also occurring when I am building from Dockerhub.

Any help??

Comment: does any `bashrc` file in current directory ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan no...there is no other file in the current directory

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan do I need a bashrc file to build docker? Or can I just delete the lines from the Dockerfile

Comment: I added a bashrc file which does nothing, but the error was still showing. So I commented out the line which was giving error. And it was built succesfully

Comment: good news ! basically, you should understand what is purpose of `bashrc` file which is existed here

Comment: But even after I added the empty bashrc file why the error was still there?

Comment: where did you add `bashrc` file? at `~/Documents/codalab_instructions/` ?

Comment: Yes in ~/Documents/codalab_instructions/

Comment: no, add that file at `~.` current folder